# Difference between using a binder and onHandleIntent at IntentService classes

Tags: android, android-service

According to the Android [API](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) an `IntentService` derived class creates a new worker thread for each received intent and passes it to the `onHandleIntent()` implementation.

So I assume (correct me if I'm wrong) my implementation should distinguish between all different kinds of intents I want to receive and then call a corresponding method within my service which handles this request. This would be all done within the worker thread, which has been created automatically in the `onStartCommand()` method.

My Question is, if a call to a binder, which just encapsulates the public methods of my service (see ["Extending the Binder class"](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) section) is being performed, will those methods be performed in dedicated worker theads as well? Or will it be done within the main app's thread? If I wanted to call a method from a homescreen Widget, would I need an additional `Messenger` to delegate those calls?

When do I use which approach anyway (`Binder` and `onStartCommand()`)?

Comment: "an IntentService derived class creates a new worker thread for each received intent and passes it to the onHandleIntent() implementation" -- no, there is just a single thread for the background work. It's a separate thread than the main application thread, but it's not one per command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IntentService` is not built for binding purposes. The [current implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/app/IntentService.java#IntentService.onHandleIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) returns `null` from its `onBind()` method.

Furthermore, the current implementation handles all requests on **separate single thread**. (Specially created when service starts). Intent messages just queue up on that thread's handler.

If you extend `IntentService`, and simply provide a `Binder` to clients, the methods of binder will be called on same thread which invokes the methods.

If you implement your own extension of `IBinder` or use `Messenger` pattern, methods will be invoked on the thread you initiate the message `Handler`.

Comment: ok, let me get this right: there is only ONE seperate worker thread, that deals with all requests via intents. But when I use a Binder, which simply provides the service's methods, they will be executed within the caller's thread (?)

Comment: @Paweł Yes , see the source yourself [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/app/IntentService.java#IntentService.onHandleIntent%28android.content.Intent%29).